# Google Visualization apply ChartRangeFilter control only on one bar in ComboChart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am building a simple dashboard, and what I want to achieve is fairly simple.

There is one ComboChart with only 3 stacked bars displayed.

The user would use the ChartRangeFilter to specify a range of dates, I want the sum of the rows corresponding to these dates to display as one stacked bar. 
On the same chart I want to display 2 other stacked bars that are NOT in that range of dates.
They would just be specific rows in the data table.

Below is the relevant code that I have working but this only displays the single stacked bar that is the sum of all the rows within the specific range of dates.

I do not know how to add the other two, where the chartrangefilter will not affect them.

Please help.

```
//-------------------------------------
var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
document.getElementById('dash'));

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
data.addColumn('number', 'E');
data.addColumn('number', 'D');
data.addColumn('number', 'O');

//add a bunch of data

    //add two rows that are 1 year ahead and 1 year behind all the other data
   //these two rows should not be affected by the chart range filter

data.sort([{column: 0}]);

//this intermediate control would be hidden so that the user can only manipulate the date ranges of the 
var intermediate_control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
'containerId': 'hidden_div',
'options': {
    // Filter by the date axis.
    'filterColumnIndex': 0,
'ui': {
    'chartType': 'ComboChart',
    'chartOptions': {
    'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
    'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'},
    'seriesType': 'bars',
    'isStacked': true
    },
    // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the sales.
    // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
    'chartView': {
    'columns': [0,1,2,3],
    },
    // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
    'minRangeSize': 86400000
}
},
// Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(today.getFullYear() - 1,0,1), 'end': new Date(today.getFullYear() - 1, 12,31)}}

});

var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
'containerId': 'control',
'options': {
// Filter by the date axis.
'filterColumnIndex': 0,
'rows' : [1],
'ui': {
    'chartType': 'ComboChart',
    'chartOptions': {
    'chartArea': {'width': '90%'},
    'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'},
    'seriesType': 'bars',
    'isStacked': true
    },
    // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the sales.
    // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
    'chartView': {
    'columns': [0,
    {
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,1);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'E'
 },
{
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,2);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'D'
 },
 {
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < r; i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,3);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'O'
 }
    ],
    },
    // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
    'minRangeSize': 86400000
}
},
// Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(today.getFullYear() - 1,0,1), 'end': new Date(today.getFullYear() - 1, today.getMonth(), today.getDate())}}
});

var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
 'chartType': 'ComboChart',
 'containerId': 'chart',
 'options': {
   // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
   'chartArea': {'height': '80%', 'width': '70%'},
   'hAxis': {'slantedText': false},
   'vAxis': {'title' : 'Sales'},
   'seriesType': 'bars',
'isStacked': true
 },
 // Convert the first column from 'date' to 'string'.
 'view': {
   'columns': [
     {
       'calc': function(dataTable, rowIndex) {
         return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, 0) + ' - ' + dataTable.getFormattedValue(dataTable.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 0);//'Last Year YTD';
       },
       'type': 'string'
     }, 
 {
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dT.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,1);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'E'
 },
{
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dT.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,2);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'D'
 },
 {
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dT.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,3);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'O'
 },
 ],
 'rows' : [0]
 }
});



dashboard.bind(intermediate_control, control);  
dashboard.bind(control, chart);

dashboard.draw(data);
console.log(data);
console.log(control);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually ended up doing this a hacky way. Let me know if anyone knows how to do this the "correct" way.

I did not append the "special" rows to the data table and in the chart options I did this

```
'view': {
   'columns': [
     {
       'calc': function(dataTable, rowIndex) {
     if (rowIndex == 1) {return 'This Year';} else if (rowIndex == 2) {return 'Last Year';} 
         return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, 0) + ' - ' + dataTable.getFormattedValue(dataTable.getNumberOfRows() - 1, 0);//'Last Year YTD';
       },
       'type': 'string'
     }, 
 {
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
    if (r == 1) {return thisYear[0];} else if (r == 2) {return lastYear[0];}
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dT.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,1);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'E'
 },
{
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
        if (r == 1) {return thisYear[1];} else if (r == 2) {return lastYear[1];}
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dT.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,2);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'D'
 },
 {
    'calc' : function(dT, r) {
        if (r == 1) {return thisYear[2];} else if (r == 2) {return lastYear[2];}
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < dT.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
        res += dT.getValue(i,3);
    }
    return res;
    },
    'type' : 'number',
    'label' : 'O'
 },
 ],
 'rows' : [1, 0, 2]
 }
});
```

where lastYear and thisYear were arrays with data corresponding to the special rows